# Google cloud composer-2 authentication for rest API

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I have been trying to use composer-2 apis through REST call. I was using id_token.fetch_id_token to generate token but it is not working for it. Please let me know if there are any ways to authenticate composer-2 apis using SA while making rest api calls from code.

Comment: Which api do you want to call ?

Comment: I want to change the DAG status inside cloud composer. Update api inshort

Comment: You want to do that with a one shot command line or inside another DAG ?

Comment: Does this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-airflow-api#access_airflow_rest_api_using_a_service_account) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags#console_1) help you?

Comment: Hi @AbhishekSingh, is your issue resolved?